# Почему я выхожу за пределы?

Tags: python, циклы, numpy, for

Почему цикл выдает ошибку:
index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5

```
s_2 = 0
matrix = numpy.zeros([5, 5])
list = ['ac','sc','fc','cf', 'mc']
list_1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']

for string in list:
    for element in list_1:
        q = string.count(element)
        matrix[s_1, s_2] = q
        s_2 += 1
    s_1 += 1
```

Comment: Почему индекс 5 выходит за пределы списка с пятью элементами или почему получается индекс 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посчитать матрицу вхождений символов можно *векторизированным* способом (не используя явных циклов):

```
In [27]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [28]: import pandas as pd

In [29]: list_ = ['ac','sc','fc','cf', 'mc']

In [30]: cv = CountVectorizer(analyzer="char", vocabulary=['a','b','c','d','e'])

In [31]: res = pd.DataFrame(cv.fit_transform(list_).A, columns=cv.get_feature_names())
```

---

результат:

```
In [32]: res
Out[32]:
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  0  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0  0
4  0  0  1  0  0
```

---

для больших текстов имеет смысл использовать разреженные структуры, которые экономят много памяти:

```
In [43]: res = (pd.SparseDataFrame(cv.fit_transform(list_), 
                                  columns=cv.get_feature_names(), 
                                  default_fill_value=0)
                  .astype("int16"))
```

---

```
In [47]: res
Out[47]:
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  0  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0  0
4  0  0  1  0  0

In [48]: res.memory_usage()
Out[48]:
Index    80
a        10
b         0
c        18
d         0
e         0
dtype: int64

In [49]: res.info()
<class 'pandas.core.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 5 columns):
a    5 non-null Sparse[int16, 0]
b    5 non-null Sparse[int16, 0]
c    5 non-null Sparse[int16, 0]
d    5 non-null Sparse[int16, 0]
e    5 non-null Sparse[int16, 0]
dtypes: Sparse[int16, 0](5)
memory usage: 108.0 bytes
```

Answer (score 3):

Надо обнулять s_2:

```
for string in list:
    s_2 = 0
    for element in list_1:
        q = string.count(element)
        matrix[s_1, s_2] = q
        s_2 += 1
    s_1 += 1
```

А в начале можно убрать.

Comment: а вот s_1 хорошо бы иницилизировать